# EmberJS - Access Controller value from application template

Tags: ember.js

Learning EmberJS in a trial by fire and one issue that comes up is from my generated linkTo's in the application header. I have a paginator on a resource such that the url becomes #/page/N. My linkTo is not capable of picking up on N from the application template, however (because i'm not in a PageController context), so the link will always be #/ even if a page is set.

What is the best way to solve this? I'm using http://hawkins.io/2013/07/pagination-with-ember/  as a base for my paginator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to access the `PageController` and it's pagination helpers from a different controller. You can do this using `needs` to get access to the `PageController`.

```
needs: 'page',
pageBinding: 'controllers.page'
```

Now you can access the `PageController` within your controller using `this.get('page')`, and use any other methods on. In the template you can also bind to `page.foo` properties.